# Отступ между маркером и краем CheckBox-а

Tags: android, checkbox

Нужно увеличить отступ между краем и маркером CheckBox, уже всё перепробовал, paddingLeft/Rigt/Start/End, использую кастомный бекгроунд, добвлял ему тоже паддинги, двигается только текст, маркер нет. Может Кто знает как победить этого зверя?

P.S. Ещё нужно что бы маркер был справа, использую layoutDirection, но в обычной версии та же проблема. Делать на основе TextView и CheckBox очень затратно, есть очень большие страницы, в которых и так более 80 вьюшек, из них CheckBox почти 20-ть штук.

Answer (score 0):

Для стандартного чекбокса любые типы отступов не работают. Но вы можете с помощью css победить стандартное решение:

**1. Скрываем стандартный чекбокс с помощью css свойства opacity:**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {opacity: 0;}
```

**2. Задаем кастомные стили для не выбранного чекбокса с помощью ::after**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:after {тут стили}
```

**3. Задаем стили для выбранного чекбокса:**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {тут стили}
```

Comment: Это для андроида? Я такой реализации в стилях никогда не видел...

Comment: это в css. Для андроида вы можете найти подробную информацию по кастомизации чексбоксов тут http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/checkbox.php . Суть в принципе такая же, просто разная реализация

Comment: Тут ничего нет, я читал, спасибо.

Comment: вопрос по нативным виджетам ОС Android, зачем вы пишите про CSS

Comment: где указано в вопросе, что это только для Android нужно?

Comment: под вопросом стоит тег android, это и значит, что вопрос по ОС Android, а ни каком ни CSS